# How to create more than one index using EF Core fluent api?

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.1

strangely I couldn't find any example or mention of this anywhere. I would like to set indexes on two of my columns (not a composite index, just two separate indexes) using the fluent api.

For example, I was wondering if it's possible to do something like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<T>
            .HasIndex(h => h.Column1)
            .HasIndex(h => h.Column2);
```

However, from the looks of it, it's not possible to chain indexes like this. Currently what I'm doing is setting them separately like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<T>
            .HasIndex(h => h.Column1)

modelBuilder.Entity<T>
            .HasIndex(h => h.Column2)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

HasIndex() returns a type of IndexBuilder which allows you to call things like .IsUnique() or .HasName() etc.

> Is there a better way to do this?

Depends if you consider this better or not, and if you REALLY want to be fluent.

To keep adding indexes using a fluent style you need to get back to the EntityTypeBuilder. If you really wanted you could use an extension method.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<T>
            .AddIndex(h => h.Column1)
            .AddIndex(h => h.Column2);

public static EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> AddIndex<TEntity>(this EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder, Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> indexExpression) where TEntity : class
{
    builder.HasIndex(indexExpression);
    return builder;
}
```

Or

```
builder.Entity<T>()
    .AddIndex(indexBuilder => indexBuilder.HasIndex(h => h.Column1))
    .AddIndex(indexBuilder => indexBuilder.HasIndex(h => h.Column2).IsUnique());

public static EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> AddIndex<TEntity>(this EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder, Action<EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity>> action) where TEntity : class
{
    action(builder);
    return builder;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In `Entity Framework 6.x` you can create indexes using both `Data Annotation` and `Fluent API` but in `EF Core` according to [EF Core Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes) documentation, so far, you can only create indexes with `Fluent API`. So what you are doing is the appropriate way of doing this in `EF Core`.

Additionally one thing you can do is separate your Entity Configuration from `DbContext` as follows:

```
public class FooConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Foo> builder)
    {
        ...
        builder.HasIndex(h => h.Column1).IsUnique();
        builder.HasIndex(h => h.Column2).IsUnique();
       ..
    }
}
```

Then apply the configuration in `OnModelCreating` method as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new FooConfiguration()); //<-- add here
}
```